# ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock in multithreded environment

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, dblink

I have two DB's where i use DB link to connect to DB2 from Db1.
I am using JDBC, C3Po jar, oracle 11g. This is a batch job runs every day.

At first run which is successful there are around 400k records inserted during merge command, during second run (its a daily job) we are facing issues. I guess the issue is because of merge query? merge has condition, if exists update otherwise insert. most likely it will re-run 400k which are mostly identical(for now) so is this looking up and update/insert causing this problem?

This is how my logic looks

```
method(){
1.select query where DBlink involved, contains Db1 and Db2 tables
2.iterate the result and using batch updates 
     save (using MERGE) the result from step 1 to a table which is not used in step 1 query.
     we are dealing with over 100k records here.
3.  stmt.executeBatch();//This is where the sql exception is occurring
            closeResultSet(rs);
            clearBatch(stmt);
            closePreparedStatement(stmt);
            closePreparedStatement(pstmt);//select statement
}
```

There is no closing of DBlink in my code. this above logic will run on 8 (greater or less) threads parallely with different inputs each having its own connection to db.
here are my thoughts and doubts

- i think each thread will create a DBlink
- do i need to increase the shared poll size as suggested by this link
  [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/e_ora_02049_timeout_distributed_transaction.htm)?
- If it is because of Dblink why am i facing exception while
  executeBatch() where there is no use of Dblink?
- I do not think closing the DBlink will work in my case. since these
  are running parallely they will mostly reach to the code at the same
  time, do i need change the configuration to have more Dblinks?

Comment: How does your step 1 query split the work across eight threads? Is the MERGE target in DB1 or DB2? Which database are you connecting to when you run this code (I guess DB1)?

Comment: @ Step1 each thread will hit the db with different inputs and gets the result and generate xmls.Merge will connect to DB1 where no DBlink is being used. I guess the issue is because of merge query?

Comment: @APC update: Step1 each thread will hit the db with different inputs, call it as different values for where clause and gets the result and generate xmls.Merge will connect to DB1 where no DBlink is being used.your guess is correct in case of connecting to DB1.
At first run which is successfull there are 400k records inserted during merge command, during second run(its a daily job) we are facing issues. I guess the issue is because of merge query? merge has condition if exists update otherwise insert. most likely it will re-run 400k which are mostly identical so we are facing this issue?

Comment: @APC above update was update to its previous comment, anyways i added more info in the question, please look in to it.